# Arabic language search in codeigniter error : Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)

Tags: mysql, join, utf-8

Arabic language search in codeigniter error :   **Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)**

*In English language search is working*

JOIN Query to use to search

```
SELECT *, `guest`.*, `guest`.`id` as `guestid`, `assistant`.`guest_id` as `assistantid` FROM `guest`
LEFT JOIN `assistant` ON `guest`.`id` = `assistant`.`guest_id`
WHERE   (
`guest`.`id` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`title` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`firstname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`middlename` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`lastname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`arabic_title` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`arabic_firstname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`arabic_middlename` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`arabic_lastname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `company_name` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `position` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`country_code` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`mobile_no` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`email` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `nationality` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `category` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `gender` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest_type` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `location` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `guest`.`remarks` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`id` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`id_user_master` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`guest_id` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`title` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`firstname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`middlename` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`lastname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`arabic_title` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`arabic_firstname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`arabic_middlename` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`arabic_lastname` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`country_code` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`mobile_no` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `assistant`.`email` LIKE '%محلل مالي%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
ORDER BY `guest`.`id` DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

in database "utf8_general_ci"

Answer (score 0):

- Check the connection for being character set utf8
- Check the application for whether it is using UTF-8

Meanwhile, that looks like an awfully slow query -- lots of `ORs` and leading wildcard on `LIKEs`.